# Mock include property in findMany with Prisma

Tags: typescript, jestjs, mocking, relationship, prisma

I have setup my project with TypeScript and Jest. I have a repository method that fetches all posts with their comments like so:

```
const data = await prisma.post.findMany({ include: { comments: true } })
```

After that I manipulate the comments via `data.comments.map(...)`. This is where my tests fail. The errors I get tell me that `data.comments` is undefined.

This is how I mock the the `findMany` method call:

```
prismaMock.site.findMany.mockResolvedValue([
  {
    id: '1',
    title: 'mock',
    text: 'test',
    commentIDs: [],
  },
])
```

If I try to add `countries: []` to the mock, then TypeScript complains by saying this property is not part of the Post type.

Is there a way to mock the data I get from the `include` part of the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out all I had to do is store the mocked data in a variable without giving it a type:

```
const mockedData = [
  {
    id: '1',
    title: 'mock',
    text: 'test',
    commentIDs: [],
  },
]
```

And then:

```
prismaMock.post.findMany. mockResolvedValue(mockedData)
```

Comment: I don't think this solution works. Typescript still complains about wrong mockedData type.